# jQuery UI autocomplete with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Alright been racking my brain on this (im terrible at this) but yea ive tried reading all i can and still cant get it to work.

trying to do autocomplete with jquery ui

my json looks like this

```
{"dealers":
     {
         "1156":"dealer 1",
         "1122":"dealer 2",
         "1176":"dealer 3",
         "1491":"dealer 4",
         "1463":"dealer 5",
         "269":"dealer 6"
    }
}
```

i am trying to use this information as the source for autocomplete.  i am getting the response object just fine I am just having trouble getting it in the right format so that I can place the "###" in a hidden field tied to the "value" which needs to be displayed as the portion of the drop down.

been trying a million different ways but a recent attempt was below

```
function ajaxCall() {
    $.getJSON("/example/location/example.json?term=" + $('#dealerName').val(),
        function(data) {
        $.each(data.dealers, function(k, v) {                
                alert(k + ' : ' + v);
        });
    });        
}

$('#dealerName').autocomplete({
    source: ajaxCall,
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
});
```

Please and thank you much!

Comment: `k` should hold the name of they key, which is what you want. What exactly isn't working with your current code?

Comment: Do a `console.log(data)` to see what `data` actually contains. If it's empty, then you likely have a problem with the script on your server.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to transform the object you are getting back into an array in the format that jQueryUI expects.

You can use [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map) to transform the `dealers` object into that array.

```
$('#dealerName').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON("/example/location/example.json?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
            response($.map(data.dealers, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value,
                    value: key
                };
            }));
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
});
```

Note that when you select an item, the "key" will be placed in the text box. You can change this by tweaking the `label` and `value` properties that `$.map`'s callback function return.

Alternatively, if you have access to the server-side code that is generating the JSON, you could change the way the data is returned. As long as the data:

- Is an array of objects that have a `label` property, a `value` property, or both, or
- Is a simple array of strings

In other words, if you can format the data like this:

```
[{ value: "1463", label: "dealer 5"}, { value: "269", label: "dealer 6" }]
```

or this:

```
["dealer 5", "dealer 6"]
```

Then your JavaScript becomes much simpler:

```
$('#dealerName').autocomplete({
    source: "/example/location/example.json"
});
```

Comment: thanks much, I am having the backend guy fix the output so that it is an array of objects

Comment: Should change "src" to "data"

Answer (score 3):

I understand that its been answered already. but I hope this will help someone in future and saves so much time and pain.

complete code is below: This one I did for a textbox to make it Autocomplete in CiviCRM. Hope it helps someone

```
CRM.$( 'input[id^=custom_78]' ).autocomplete({
            autoFill: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                    var label = ui.item.label;
                    var value = ui.item.value;
                    // Update subject field to add book year and book product
                    var book_year_value = CRM.$('select[id^=custom_77]  option:selected').text().replace('Book Year ','');
                    //book_year_value.replace('Book Year ','');
                    var subject_value = book_year_value + '/' + ui.item.label;
                    CRM.$('#subject').val(subject_value);
                    CRM.$( 'input[name=product_select_id]' ).val(ui.item.value);
                    CRM.$('input[id^=custom_78]').val(ui.item.label);
                    return false;
            },
            source: function(request, response) {
                CRM.$.ajax({
                    url: productUrl,
                        data: {
                                        'subCategory' : cj('select[id^=custom_77]').val(),
                                        's': request.term,
                                    },
                    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                        xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
                    },

                    success: function(result){
                                result = jQuery.parseJSON( result);
                                //console.log(result);
                                response(CRM.$.map(result, function (val,key) {
                                                         //console.log(key);
                                                         //console.log(val);
                                                         return {
                                                                 label: val,
                                                                 value: key
                                                         };
                                                 }));
                    }
                })
                .done(function( data ) {
                    if ( console && console.log ) {
                     // console.log( "Sample of dataas:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
                    }
                });
            }
  });
```

PHP code on how I'm returning data to this jquery ajax call in autocomplete:

```
/**
 * This class contains all product related functions that are called using AJAX (jQuery)
 */
class CRM_Civicrmactivitiesproductlink_Page_AJAX {
  static function getProductList() {
        $name   = CRM_Utils_Array::value( 's', $_GET );
    $name   = CRM_Utils_Type::escape( $name, 'String' );
    $limit  = '10';

        $strSearch = "description LIKE '%$name%'";

        $subCategory   = CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'subCategory', $_GET );
    $subCategory   = CRM_Utils_Type::escape( $subCategory, 'String' );

        if (!empty($subCategory))
        {
                $strSearch .= " AND sub_category = ".$subCategory;
        }

        $query = "SELECT id , description as data FROM abc_books WHERE $strSearch";
        $resultArray = array();
        $dao = CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery( $query );
        while ( $dao->fetch( ) ) {
            $resultArray[$dao->id] = $dao->data;//creating the array to send id as key and data as value
        }
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    CRM_Utils_System::civiExit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use sql prepare statements if you don't want to be hacked.

Answer (score 1):

I use this script for autocomplete...

```
$('#custmoers_name').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

        // $.getJSON("<?php echo base_url('index.php/Json_cr_operation/autosearch_custmoers');?>", function (data) {
          $.getJSON("Json_cr_operation/autosearch_custmoers?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
          console.log(data);
            response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                console.log(value);
                return {
                    label: value.label,
                    value: value.value
                };
            }));
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    delay: 100
});
```

My json return :- `[{"label":"Mahesh Arun Wani","value":"1"}]` after search `m`

but it display in dropdown `[object object]`...

Comment: Please give me a suggestion?