# CakePHP 3 - Search suggestions

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to create a search suggestion input box with Cakephp 3. I found a tutorial online and i'm trying to implement it but i don't get a suggestion as mentioned in the tutorial. 
(http://www.naidim.org/cakephp-3-tutorial-18-autocomplete)

**PagesController.php**

```
public function chargesadd()
 {
    $this->loadModel('Charges');

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $name = $this->request->query['term'];
    $results = $this->Customers->find('all', [
        'conditions' => [ 'OR' => [
            'name LIKE' => $name . '%',
            'id LIKE' => $name . '%',
        ]]
    ]);
    $resultsArr = [];
    foreach ($results as $result) {
         $resultsArr[] =['label' => $result['name'], 'value' => $result['id']];
    }
    echo json_encode($resultsArr);
 }
}
```

**chargesadd.ctp**

```
<?php use Cake\Routing\Router; ?>

<?php 
  echo $this->Form->input('customer_id', ['type' => 'text']);
?>

<script>
    jQuery('#customer-id').autocomplete({
         source:'<?php echo Router::url(array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'chargesadd')); ?>',
        minLength: 3
    });
</script>
```

I have a feeling there's something wrong with the **$resultsArr** how it's been outputted. But i can't properly figure out what's wrong with it.

I'm using CakePHP 3.4.7

Comment: what do you output get?

Comment: @PankajMakwana nothing. Earlier i got a 500 error because i was using the wrong model. Now i'm using the one i need and i'm not getting anything at all.

Comment: Checkout this post this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435433/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json

Comment: call `exit();` after `echo json_encode($resultsArr);`  To make sure that other data except json is not comming from the server

Comment: @VivekD. Tried adding exit(); no difference. Still no result showing up.

Comment: Any other method of search suggestion methods?

Comment: first test your api with postman to see if your controller action is working true.

Comment: @Beaumind There is no JSON conversion taking place – the controller action is just echoing out plain text separated by new lines

Comment: @KasunWijesekara you should correct your code first you load `Charges` Model but you run query `Customers` Model. I think you should use `$this->loadModel('Customers');`

Comment: Also do not echo data from controller actions! **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable**

Comment: @tarikul05 yea i corrected that. I forgot to update the thread sorry.

Comment: @ndm understood. Thanks!

Comment: Is that working now @KasunWijesekara ?

Comment: @tarikul05 I did that and it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method but it didn't work out for some reason, if someone is trying to do an autocomplete feature or a search suggestion feature try this out.

( https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ )

You need to generate the dropdown. That's basically it. And add the "selectpicker" class and the relevant cdn resources.

```
<select class="selectpicker">
 <option>Mustard</option>
 <option>Ketchup</option>
 <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/Rio517/pen/NPLbpP